# Necessary condition (s) for the divisibility relation $(2a+b) \mid (a+b)^{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If
$n \geq 2$
is an integer and
$a, b > 0$
are integers such that
$$(2a + b) \mid (a+b)^n,$$
what relations necessarily follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a+b\equiv -a\pmod{2a+b}$, we find $a^n\equiv 0\pmod{2a+b}$. Especially, any prime $p$ dividing $2a+b$ must also divide $a$ (and hence also $b$)

Answer (score 1):

let $a+b=s$ and $a=t$. What are the conditions for $s+t | t^n$?

Well clearly $s$ and $t$ can't be relatively prime, but that's about all we can say about them.